# What does ${2%.*} mean?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am reading a bash script that takes two arguments in input but I can't figure out what does

```
${2%.*}
```

does exactly, can someone explain me what does the curly braces, 2, %, "." and * refers two?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$2` is the second argument passed to the program. That is, if your script was run with

```
myscript foo.txt bar.jpg
```

`$2` would have the value `bar.jpg`.

The `%` operator removes a suffix from the value that matches the following pattern. `.*` matches a period (`.`) followed by zero or more characters. Put together, your expression removes a single extension from the value. Using the above example,

```
$ echo ${2%.*}
bar
```

P.S. Perhaps worth noting that `%` will remove the *shortest* match for the following pattern: So if `$2` was for example `bar.jpg.xz`, then `${2%.*}` would be `bar.jpg`. (Conversely, the `%%` operator will remove the *longest* match for the pattern, so ${2%%.*} would be `bar` in both examples.)